# Oracle Jet RESTDataProvider does not fulfill table

Tags: typescript, asynchronous, oracle-jet

I am working on an Oracle Jet Project and I am trying to fill a table with data from a request.

I have confirmed that the data does get pulled through though it seems the issue is the data is populated with records AFTER it is set as my variables since the request and response functions are async. So the data is being injected into the table before any data is actually present and then it doesn't dynamically update once the dataprovider has changed.
[Log of order of outputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fQIR.png)
Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was completely seperate.

The data was required to be a json object not a json array so it didn't think it had anything to display.

Comment: Use answered himself, explaing/suggesting the chnages that works for him